# How to turn off the difference prompt in GoLand？

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, goland

After upgrading GoLand to the latest version, it has used the GitLab function. As long as the MR function of GitLab is turned on, there will be a difference prompt in the code, and it cannot be turned off. The tutorial on the official website will not take effect if it is turned off. Where can I turn off this diff prompt?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to find the answer on the official website, but it didn’t take effect after following the settings on the official website: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-changes-information.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must click on the icon on the picture and disable review mode:

[image]